# How to traverse SharePoint Library in Client Object Model?

Tags: 2010, document-library, client-object-model, sharepoint-library

I have SharePoint Library and i want to traverse all folder and sub folder of it using client object model. 
Can anybody have solution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Following code will Display all Libraries and Folders of each Library in Treeview

```
private void frmForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ClientContext clientcontext= new ClientContext("http://your server"))
    {

        //Load Libraries from SharePoint
        clientcontext.Load(clientcontext.Web.Lists);
        clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (List list in clientcontext.Web.Lists)
        {
           try
           {
                if (list.BaseType.ToString() == "DocumentLibrary" && !list.IsApplicationList && !list.Hidden && list.Title != "Form Templates" && list.Title != "Customized Reports" && list.Title != "Site Collection Documents" && list.Title != "Site Collection Images" && list.Title != "Images")
                {
                    clientcontext.Load(list);
                    clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
                    clientcontext.Load(list.RootFolder);
                    clientcontext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
                    clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
                    TreeViewLibraries.ShowLines = true;
                    TreeNode LibraryNode = new TreeNode(list.Title);
                    TreeViewLibraries.Nodes.Add(LibraryNode);
                        foreach (Folder SubFolder in list.RootFolder.Folders)
                        {
                            if (SubFolder.Name != "Forms")
                            {
                                TreeNode MainNode = new TreeNode(SubFolder.Name);
                                LibraryNode.Nodes.Add(MainNode);
                                FillTreeViewNodes(SubFolder, MainNode, clientcontext);
                            }
                        }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}


//Recursive Function

public void FillTreeViewNodes(Folder SubFolder, TreeNode MainNode, ClientContext clientcontext)
{
    clientcontext.Load(SubFolder.Folders);
    clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (Folder Fol in SubFolder.Folders)
        {
            TreeNode SubNode = new TreeNode(Fol.Name);
            MainNode.Nodes.Add(SubNode);
            FillTreeViewNodes(Fol, SubNode, clientcontext);
        }
}
```

You can modify the code as per your requirement :-)

**Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough ... I'd this today ... here you go ...

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint/web");
        clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='Recursive' />";
        ListItemCollection docs = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName").GetItems(query);
        clientContext.Load(docs);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

After that just foreach through the listitems returned by docs.

Comment: It should be query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll ' />";  Even the sub folders must be traversed.

Comment: Or simply, you can do the following:
CamlQuery query = CreateAllFoldersQuery();

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Main()
    {

        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(@"https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/PAF/"))
        {

            var passWord = new System.Security.SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "NextGenReport@2014".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("smsprpt@microsoft.com", passWord);
            var uploadFilePath = @"G:\\RFY\\SMB\\Weekly Refresh\\SMB_RFY_V1.1 - Weekly Refresh.xlsx";
            using (var fs = new FileStream(uploadFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {

                var fi = new FileInfo(uploadFilePath);
                var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Reports");
                clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
                clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, "/teams/PAF/Reports/FY15 Reporting/Partner/SMB_RFY_V1.1 - Weekly Refresh.xlsx", fs, true);

            }
        }


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it through SPQuery:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

//Condition to check the item type is folder or not
query.Query = “<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=’FSObjType’/><Value Type=’Lookup’>1</Value></Eq></Where>”;

//Get all the items including subfolders from the list 
query.ViewAttributes = “Scope=’RecursiveAll’”;
```

[look at this post](http://www.ktskumar.com/blog/2009/07/retrieve-all-folders-from-list/)

Comment: **SPQuery** is not a part of Client Object Modal. You can not use this in COM.